# Get name(or index) of selected menu item from context menu, which was dynamically generated via ItemsSource bound to a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a context menu that contains 1 menu item. That menu item is bound to a ObservableCollection for the itemssource.

```
         <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Example Menu Item" 
                          Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ExampleCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableItems}">
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
```

How do I get the name (or index) of the menu item that was selected. The problem is I cannot bind a command to each individual menu item, as they are dynamically generated.

For example how would I know which item was clicked, as seen in the image below?

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still can bind `Command` and `CommandParameter` per item for dynamically generated lists but you need to use `ItemContainerStyle`

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Example Menu Item" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableItems}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ExampleCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

in this example `CommandParameter`, which is passed to you `ExampleCommand` command as parameter, will be an item in your collection (current `DataContext` of child item)

**EDIT**

To get index you can use pair of `ItemsControl` properties: `AlternationCount` and `AlternationIndex`. You set [`AlternationCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount(v=vs.110).aspx) to number of items in your collection and pass `AlternationIndex` to your command

```
<MenuItem Header="Example Menu Item" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableItems}" AlternationCount="{Binding ObservableItems.Count}">
   <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ...}"/>
         <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"/>
      </Style>
   </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: would it be possible to get the selected index, rather than the observablecollection item?

Comment: if you have item and collection get index from there (it's in the same `DataContext`)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean? Do you mean iterating through the collection?

Comment: it should be as easy as using [`IndexOf(T item)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132410(v=vs.110).aspx) method like `var idx = ObservableItems.IndexOf(selectedItem)`

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, the problem is that my collection is made up of strings, which can be duplicate.

Comment: check my edit and you should get index of an item instead of item